Renormalization in holomorphic dynamics
Renormalization seems to play an ever increasing in scope and importance role in the field of holomorphic dynamics, but there seem to be hardly any modern resources adressing the principal ideas cohearently and in a unified fashion.
There are countless papers using renormalization techniques in dynamics to prove a variety of results, but in order for a student trying to enter the field, learning about renormalization seems quite a daunting task, given its intrinsic difficulty - at least to my eyes.
Are there any resources that introduce, or explain the renormalization concept in holomorphic dynamics other than McMullen's book "Complex Dynamics and Renormalization", which is focus to proving a very specific result?

The MO answer here provides some references to consider.
